# How to scroll with jQuery (Bottom of element should be at the bottom of the page)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On my HTML page, I have stuff that can be added dynamically by a button.
When the stuff that is added is not in the viewport anymore, I want to scroll to get it into the viewport.
As the added content is always added below the clickable button that adds the stuff i always want to have the bottom of the element to be at the bottom of the viewport after scrolling, but i am just able to put the top of the element at the top of the viewport with that function:

```
if (!elementInViewport(document.getElementById("ElementId"))){
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#ElementId").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

There is no `scrollBottom` instead of `scrollTop` and when I replace the `offset().top` with `offset().bottom` the function doesn't do anything at all.

How can I do that?

Comment: Make a reproducible example, pls.

Comment: Did you try `scrollTop: $("#ElementId").offset().top - $("ElementId").height()` ?

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, that didnt scroll exactly where i wanted but it was a good start.. But now i am using the solution from ATP, which works very nice

Comment: @s.kuznetsov i was trying but i couldnt do it that fast, sry

Comment: @lxg95, no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function:

```
if (!elementInViewport(document.getElementById("ElementId"))){
   document.getElementById("ElementId").scrollIntoView(false);
}
```

Comment: Nice that is working, Thank you :)

i also added 

```html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}```

to my css so it scrolls a little bit nicer.